# Dynamically generating controls in WPF using Prism, MVVM, MEF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I am using WPF with Prism and MEF for my application. There was a need to create controls dynamically. And so here is my problem!!

As far as I know I should not be having code in my code behind (SomeFile.xaml.cs) to keep my code easily testable. And so the code should be actually moved to ViewModel.

But my code generates UI controls dynamically. And I dont think that the ViewModel should know anything about the Controls.

So where and how should I go about writing this code?? What would be the right approach?
Hope I made myself clear!

Thanks

Comment: what kind of "controls" do you need to create "dynamically"? You probably need an `ItemsControl`. Post a screenshot of what you need.

Answer (score 8):

When working with WPF/MVVM, your data layer is your application (the [DataContext](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)), and you use things like `Templates` to tell WPF how to draw your application components to the UI.

For example, suppose you're given the task to dynamically render a bunch of controls.

The WinForms way might have been to loop through your objects, create a UI control for each object, then add the UI control to the screen.

However with WPF/MVVM, you would instead create a class representing each object (a `Model`), and give WPF a list of those classes to display.

There are many different controls WPF can use to draw a list of objects, but the most basic of them is probably an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I have some examples of a simple `ItemsControl` on [my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) if you're interested.

Now even though you've given WPF the list of your objects to render, and told it what control to use to render the list, it still probably doesn't know how to draw your object. The usual solution for this is to include an XAML template of some kind to tell it how to draw your object.

Here's a simple example template that is used to tell WPF how to draw an object of type `MyClassObject`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClassObject}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I hope that helps get you going in the right direction :)

Comment: As always, your contributions are excellent. I didn't want to write an answer myself because I was hoping for some clarifications from the OP, but most probably your answer fits perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @HighCore :) I agree, the question could use a bit more clarification as it's hard to tell exactly what is wanted, but hopefully this will give the OP enough information to get started

Comment: @Rachel - your blog link didn't work for me. My browser says "•Make sure the web address http://rachel53461.wordpress.com is correct." When asking the browser for more info it said the remote address rejected the Connection. Most (if not all) wordpress.com links don't work for me - is there something to do with my configuration?

Comment: @infowanna I don't know a lot about how wordpress is configured, however I know for comments, I'm given the option to mark them as Spam. Perhaps if an IP is marked as Spam enough times, it gets blocked? That's just a guess though, you'd have to ask WordPress about why its blocking you.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, the view has the responsibility to render the data/model provided by the viewmodel.  While it is ideal to keep as much of the model->view translation logic in the viewmodel, creation of controls adds significant complexity to move to the viewmodel, because of the coupling or infrastructure that it could add.

While you could:
1) Give the viewmodel direct access to the view, allowing it to create controls directly
   This adds coupling...
2) Create an interface on the view to manipulate controls
   This means the view must be passed (not simply bound) to the viewmodel
3) Create an abstraction of controls to bind to the view, and have the view render based on the abstraction created by the viewmodel
   This adds a maintenance nightmare as your control set expands.

I suggest exposing the model (either directly or wrapped in micro-viewmodels) via a property on the main viewmodel, and binding that to a property on the view via xaml, such that any PropertyChanged on the viewmodel will send an update to the view.  Use the model information and your control creation logic inside the view to clear and re-create the controls and bind the model dynamically to the controls you create.  This will simplify both the creation and binding of the controls, and you won't have to practice any voodoo to get information entered into the controls back into your model.

Note that even if you created an intermediary class (an attached behavior, adorner, or something else), it will still need to be able to access the view's control structure directly to attach the generated controls to the visual tree, which may cause other problems.

Comment: All of your suggestions are ugly. Use an `ItemsControl`. Period. Why would do overcomplicate it all by doing all this?

Comment: @HighCore please feel free to supply an answer, if you have one.  "Use an ItemsControl" is vague, and also assumes he wants a list of controls rather than some other layout mechanism.  Yes, dynamic control creation is ugly, especially in the context of MVVM where we are attempting to avoid use of CodeBehind and use binding for everything we can.

Comment: @BahriGundor I cannot provide a specific answer because the OP has not given a specific question. That's why I asked for clarification. My point still stands, "dynamic control creation" in the sense of procedural winforms-like code is completely unneeded in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore Why don't you submit an answer demonstrating how he could, for instance, use an ItemsControl with type mapped DataTemplates that would create and databind to elements provided by the viewmodel?  That is a simplistic, but valid, approach.  I just think it is limited in too many ways.  It might be what he needs.